# Adjust width and height of Google Maps API

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I know there are other questions like this, but none of them have helped solve my problem. I am adding a Google map to my site, but have been unable to adjust the width and height. I have tried playing with the #map css properties, I have added a container and that hasn't worked either. When I open up DevTools in my browser, there seem to be a bunch of internal styling defaults that keep the map set to cover the entire page. Nothing I do seems to make a difference. Has anyone else had this issue and how did you fix it?

App.js where I am adding the map

```
class App extends React.Component{
render() {
    return (
      <div className="google-map">
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={14}
        initialCenter={{ lat: 38.9072, lng: -77.0369 }}
        >
        {this.state.places.map(place => {
          return (
            <Marker
              onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
              name={place.name}
              position={{ lat: place.lat, lng: place.long}}
             />
          )
        })} 
      </Map>     
      </div> 
  )}
}
```

App.css

```
.google-map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }

#map {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%; 
 }
```

Comment: If set 100% of height at container ".google-map", of course that ocupate all page.

Comment: @ErnestoGonzalezMartin changing container width and height doesn't do anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Could it also be achieved with app.js
see:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-apps-with-the-google-maps-api-and-google-maps-react

const mapStyles = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%'
};

Comment: That was so simple! Don't know how I couldn't figure that out but thank you much!